# Is there a way to force update tables metadata?

Tags: google-bigquery

Since streaming tables does not update tables metadata immediately. It happens that a table does not have valid Metadata (especially with smaller tables). This, in turn, causes problems when using table wildcard functions (as they relate to tables metadata).
In order to overcome this, I am looking for a way to force update the table metadata. Is there any kind of job I can initiate to do that?
Thanks

Comment: Can you give a specific example of the problem you are encountering? I'm not sure what the problem is... Some specific questions: are you pre-creating tables or using template tables (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#template-tables)? What kind of Invalid Metadata do you see? When do you see this?Thank you!

Comment: I create a table and then streams data into it. Anyways, i am looking for a mean to force update the table metadata and not wait for some background process to get to it on unclear schedule.

Comment: Are you referring to streaming into template tables, and the creation of the associated table? Or are you instead talking about the table statistics (bytes, rows, etc) on the table metadata?

Comment: We use insert all to stream data. The question is not about streaming. Its about force update of the table metadata. Such as number of records, update time, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. The streaming system buffers streamed data in a different storage format/system than the data is normally stored in. We periodically flush the buffered data into the traditional storage system, at which point the table metadata that you're interested is updated for the chunk of data that is flushed.

The reason for this behavior is that in an actively streaming system, those statistics are potentially constantly changing, and thus will be inaccurate. Because the streaming ingestion service is a distributed system, the only way to obtaining accurate statistics about buffered data is to **scan** the buffer an calculate the update statistics (which would likely be incorrect/stale by the time the response is returned, and would also be very expensive).  We chose to keep those statistics tied to "flushed" data to keep the metadata values stable, as well as avoid requiring an expensive buffer scan to return data that is likely incorrect by the time it is returned.

We do have a section within the table metadata called "streamingBuffer", which provide estimates on rows/bytes, as well as some timing statistics.

I see from your question that you're actually using the info from table wildcards (I assume you mean TABLE_QUERY?). I will file a bug internally to include the estimated data from the streamingBuffer section in fields available to table query.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a mean to force flush the buffer?

Comment: Currently the maximum time is ~90 minutes. Depending on your data volume, we'll flush faster.

Comment: May i suggest to flush the buffer also according to stream frequency (i.e.: if there were no data streamed for x seconds then flush)

Comment: We'd definitely not do something on the scale of seconds... but perhaps something on the order of minutes of idleness would be reasonable. The thing to remember here is that one of the goals of our system is to generate optimally sized chunks of data, as query performance can be negatively effected if chunks are too large or small.